# How to make a node modules available in the browser like *socket.io* does

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, browserify

Using [socket.io](https://socket.io/), and its [documentation](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/), when installing and requiring the module `socket.io` like,

[image]

You can also load the client library in the browser like,

[image]

Without configuring any particular build-chain, or running a Browserify command or whatever.

**How do they do that?**

Answer (score 1):

They have separate repos for the client and server versions of the library.

The server side version is this: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io
And this is the client : https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client

They use Gulp script to build the standalone JS file which is situated in the `dist` folder. You can check the `gulpfile` for details on that.

When you load the client the CommonJS way, the file `lib/index.js` is getting loaded since it is mentioned as the main/entry script in the package.json like this `"main": "./lib/index"`

I hope this answers your question

Comment: Thanks, but that wouldn't explain how the route "socket.io/socket.io.js" is exposed isn't?

Comment: @adelriosantiago Actually the socket io server has a dependency on 'socket.io-client'. You can see that in the `package.json`. It then serves this client library automatically. The code for that is available at Line 105 in `https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/lib/index.js`